# Dynamically change a div's CSS attribute class php

Tags: php, css, html

After viewing 4 data I want to change a div's class. Suppose when it is 4 data the div will be  after 4 data the div will be  dynamically.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<?php 
    $i=0;
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product WHERE featured = 'featured' ORDER BY id DESC");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        if($i == 4){ echo '<div class="item active">';}
        elseif($i != 4){ echo '<div class="item">'; }
?>
     <div class="single-wid-product sel-pd">
        <img src="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" alt="" class="product-thumb">
     </div>

    </div>
    <?php $i++; } ?>

</div>
```

[image]

In that picture it is a carousel. It has 4 items active. And the div is

```
<div class="item active">
 <p>Item 1</p>
 <p>Item 2</p>
 <p>Item 3</p>
 <p>Item 4</p>
</div>
```

When it's doing autoplay (for the rest products) the div is

```
<div class="item">
 <p>Item 5</p>
 <p>Item 6</p>
 <p>Item 7</p>
 <p>Item 8</p>
</div>
```

And for others the div is

```
   <div class="item">
     <p>Item 5</p>
     <p>Item 6</p>
     <p>Item 7</p>
     <p>Item 8</p>
    </div>
```

So I want to make to merge all those divs. For the first 4 items the div class will be "item active" and for the rest items the class will be "item". It will be changed dynamically.

Comment: What are you trying to make happen? What have you tried? Your current explanation is hard to understand.

Comment: When it fetch 4 row data from database the div will be 
<div class="item active"></div>   after 4 row data the div will be <div class="item"></div>

Comment: So you want to make the 4th row of data have that, but no other row?

Comment: I have some products in database. When fetching 4 data the div's class will be "item active" for the rest data the class will be "item"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a PHP ternary operator right on your HTML for this. You can do that in this manner:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    ?>
        <div class="item <?= ($i == 4) ? "active" : "" ?>">
            ...
        </div>
    <?php 

    $i++;
}
```

Note: `<?= '' ?>` is the same as `<?php echo '' ?>`

Comment: I would recommend this method.

Comment: It's work, but its showing only one data. but I want after fetching 4 data the div's class will be changed

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean. Please be more detailed.

Comment: So, it sounds like after the 4th iteration, you want all to items to have the `"active"` class. If thats the case you have to look at `$i` as @IncredibleHat mentioned. Keep in mind that you are declaring `$i` as `$i=0` before the loop begins, meaning that the first iteration `$i` is `0`, then `1`, `2`.. so you check if `$i > 3` to apply the active to all items after the 4th iteration.

Comment: Can you please check my question again. Now I have described with details as per I can. @CodeGodie

Comment: and also @IncredibleHat

Comment: So, the updated question really puts a different spin on the needed solution, since you are showing some `<p>` tags which don't exist in your php code. So it now looks like you want to group 4 items into a single div, where that parent container has the `active` class on the first, but not the remaining groups of 4 items. Heh... uhhhh ... thats a whole new question now! ;)